# What is the harmonic rhythm in this bar?

Tags: theory

Is from Rachmanioff op 33 no 4... Is this simply a chord per beat or is there a mixture. Sometimes it appears as if there is a chord that lasts a dotted quaver followed by a chord that lasts a semi quaver per beat? I've attached a link to the score I'm describing[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/q19RPHQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harmonies are the following:

d minor (two beats) -> F major (one beat) -> C major (one beat);
Eb major (one beat) -> g minor (one beat) -> Bb major (one beat) -> d minor (one beat)

The notes you're seeing that don't belong to the harmonies are melodic/ornamental notes, i.e. passing notes, so they are not considered in regard to the harmony.